# Why does this button not align?

Tags: html, css

CSS:

```css
.button {

  color: black;
  background: lightblue;
  text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.button:hover {
  color: #FFF;
  background: green;
}
```

HTML:

```html
 <button class="button" type="submit" value="Submit"/>Submit</button>
```

I am trying to align the `button` to the center but it is not happening. Is this because I used `class` or what?

I would prefer to not use class, but I tried that and it wouldn't work either, so I just stuck with class since I found out I could do the `hover` with it.

Could you explain also why I would use the `type` and `value` inside the `button`? I found example code like this and I copied it, but I'm not sure how it works.

Comment: We don't have enough HTML & CSS context. What do you want the button to be in the center of?

Comment: Just in the center of the screen. That is all I need.

Comment: [Documentation of `<button>` elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button).

Comment: We need more than that because it may be affected by the div it's in etc.

Comment: `text-align: center;` will align the text. To align the button try with `margin: 0 auto;` Add fiddle of your code if possible. http://jsfiddle.net/ut4vx7wL/1/ Demo of center element without wrapper.

Comment: ok. I is not in a `div` it is just as is

Comment: @roger remove the '/' from `value="Submit"/>` because `button` is not a self close tag.

Comment: ok, will do this, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just convert button into Block Element by using `display:block`. So that I can use **margin**  property on it, to put it in center. Long and short, put these lines of codes in your .button css code.

```
display:block;
margin:auto;
```

Here is the result https://jsfiddle.net/p1q3xy00/14/

I really have no idea why the heck someone would use value and type attributes inside **button** tag. Actually they are used in **input** tag to specify the properties of element. For example *value* acts like a placeholder while *type* defines the format of input. It can be a checkbox, email, password, text, date, color etc.

Comment: Thanks! this is the best answer I have gotten! Your help is appreciated, I also thought the same thing about the value and type. :)

Answer (score 2):

wrap your button with a div tag and provide the alignment to the div.

```
<div style="text-align:center">
    <button class="button" type="submit" value="Submit"/>Submit</button>
</div>
```

There's three types for the button input

**button**: just a button and doesn't cause any events to occur. So, you'll have to provide events on your own.

**submit**: submits the form to which it is associated to.

**reset**: clears the fields in the form to which it is associated to.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to align the button to the center of the page, you can add a wrapper around it and center it in there

```css
.button {
  color: black;
  background: lightblue;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.button:hover {
  color: #FFF;
  background: green;
}
.wrapper {
    text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <button class="button" type="submit" value="Submit"/>Submit</button>
<div>
```

Comment: @roger No it does not need to be called 'wrapper'. I used the name for make clear it is only a wrapper tag. You could call the class something like `center-content` ... but that's entirely up to you.

Answer (score 0):

You could just add `text-align:center` to the parent element

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}
.button {
  color: black;
  background: lightblue;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.button:hover {
  color: #FFF;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<button class="button" type="submit" value="Submit" />Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `display: block; margin: 0 auto;` to `.button` make it as a block element.

Answer (score 0):

Add `display: block` to `.button` so that it can recognize `margin`